# Pourquoi les Français parlent-ils plus vite que les autres francophones (et qu’avant)?

Tags: histoire, linguistique, comparaison-de-langues, apprentissage

Je n’ai jamais parlé couramment le français (ma langue maternelle est le néerlandais), mais pour moi il est plus facile de comprendre le français quand des francophones non français le parlent... J’ai récemment rencontré beaucoup de Français et je n'arrive pas à parler français avec eux parce qu’il parlent trop vite et pas clairement.

Pour moi, ce qui est  bizarre c’est que je peux comprendre les francophones non français. Jusqu'à présent, quand j’ai parlé Français avec des Congolais ou des Marocains, je n'ai jamais eu de problèmes. Quand un Français parle, ça sonne comme « un fleuve de français », un fleuve de mots que je ne comprends pas parce que je ne distingue pas quand les mots commencent et se terminent.

Mon ami m’a dit que les Français parlaient plus lentement et clairement, avec plus d’intonation, dans le passé. On a regardé des interviews en français des années quinze et je peux les comprendre plus facilement.

Cela m’a fait me demander pourquoi je comprends les francophones non français. Est-il possible que les gens des anciennes colonies françaises parlent français comme les « vieux Français »? Et pourquoi les Français ont-ils commencé à parler plus vite et moins clairement qu’avant? Ou bien, est-ce que je m’imagine tout ça ?

Comment: To be honest I also find it easier to understand Dutch when spoken by non-native speakers. Same thing for English (in which I'm more fluent though so this is less of a problem), as long as the accent is good enough. I'm not sure whether people now speak faster, but maybe this is also a matter of diction and pronunciation, not only speed (although they're somehow linked)

Comment: Les années quinze ?

Comment: Possibly to do with stress timing v syllable timing. I think this is a pretty crude categorisation but Dutch is said to be a stress timed language whereas French is said to be syllable timed. As a Dutch speaker you are probably looking for stress patterns to break down the stream of sound into words, but they are not really there in French (do you have an easier time in English / German?) From what I can see on YT, a Congolese accent does have quite marked stress. I would guess that is due to the influence of local languages. IME speech always *seems* faster when you can't make out the words.

Comment: Les Congolais et Marocains n'ont en général pas le français comme langue maternelle. Est-ce que tu considères qu'un francophone Bruxellois, un Namurois, un Carolorégien ou un Genevois sont aussi des francophones non Français ?

Comment: Bien que la question puisse effectivement apparaître comme "opinion-biased" (subjective), ne reposant sur aucune étude (?) il est sans doute intéressant d'analyser pourquoi cette perception existe. Il y a une raison linguistique (liée à la prosodie), reste à déterminer laquelle.

Answer (score 5):

Il est difficile de dire que "les français parlent rapidement": la France est un grand pays, et chaque région de ce pays a ses subtilités dans l'utilisation de la langue.

Le français qu'on entend à la télévision est, bien souvent, le français (accent et débit) "parisien": les Parisiens sont connus pour parler rapidement.

Les gens du sud de la France auront parfois tendance à parler plus lentement mais avec un accent différent qui peut rendre la compréhension difficile. Et l'accent n'est pas le même entre Sud-Ouest et Sud-Est.

Les gens du Nord ont, souvent, un débit de parole rapide et un accent très difficile à comprendre... mais encore une fois, cela varie en fonction de la région: les gens de Normandie ont un débit "normal", les gens du Pas-de-Calais un débit plus rapide, les gens d'Alsace un débit plus lent.
L'accent, à mes yeux, le plus difficile à comprendre est celui de Picardie et du Nord-Pas-de-Calais.

En outre, au delà de la langue, c'est surtout une question d'individus: certains parlent vite, d'autres plus lentement.
Le fait que le français soit la langue maternelle (et donc parfaitement maîtrisée) doit beaucoup jouer.

**NOTE IMPORTANTE**: toutes ses affirmations sont basées sur mes constats personnels: j'ai vécu en Picardie 10 ans, en région parisienne 17 ans et dans le sud-est 9 ans. J'ai également passé quelques mois en Alsace et Normandie.

Comment: L'accent méridional est souvent au contraire perçu comme plus facile à comprendre par les non-francophones car il présente moins d'élisions et préserve un accent tonique pour chaque mot, ce qui a essentiellement disparu en français "du nord".

Answer (score -3):

Il faut vous dire qu'il y a Français et Français ! Être français ne donne pas la garantie automatique d'un bon parler français ! Je crois que très possiblement vous avez été exposé à du monde venant de France qui ne soigne pas toujours sa prononciation, même lorsque conscient de la difficulté supplémentaire et parfois grande à laquelle font face les étrangers. Je pense personnellement qu'après un court préliminaire de conversation qui permet d'apprécier le niveau de l'interlocuteur dans notre langue maternelle nous avons le plus souvent, humains de toutes nationalités, la présence d'esprit d'ajuster notre expression, tant du point de vue du vocabulaire et des formes, que l'on choisira selon qu'elles sont plus ou moins simples, tant de celui de la rapidité de l'élocution que l'on règle facilement de lente à rapide, pourvu que l'on ait un minimum de bonne volonté. Peut-être n'avez-vous pas encore rencontré un bon Français !

Pour ce qui est de la façon de parler des Français en général et en particulier entre eux on peut dire au moins une chose qui ne corrobore pas ce que vous dites: sur le plan de l'« emboutissage » des mots, qui est dû aux règles de liaisons particulières et nombreuses de la langue française et qui peut être gênant avant d'en avoir pris l'habitude, il existe un phénomène qui persiste depuis quelques décades, celui-ci étant que les gens font de moins en moins de liaisons, c'est à dire qu'ils ont tendance à prononcer les mots « détachés » les uns des autres. Au vu du ralentissement de l'élocution que l'absence de liaisons entraine et au vu d'une définition plus nette des mot le niveau de clarté devrait être plus grand, pas inférieur. En ce qui concerne la rapidité de l'élocution je ne trouve pas qu'il y ait vraiment eu un changement. Il y a des variations selon les tempéraments et/ou les circonstances mais la rapidité normale n'est pas différente de ce qu'elle était il y a cinquante années passées.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103087/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-pourquoi-les-francais-parlent-ils-plus-vite-que-les).

Comment: Dans le cadre d'une discussion avec 2 intervenants, on peut effectivement imaginer un des 2 interlocuteurs adapter sa vitesse et sa diction pour l'autre (et encore, cela demande un certain effort), dans le cadre d'une discussion avec de multiples interlocuteurs, j'ai du mal à concevoir cela. Je suis dans le même cas actuellement, bossant dans une boite flamande les discussions à table le midi sont extrêmement difficile à suivre pour moi et je ne m'attends pas à ce que ce groupe parle tout d'un coup au ralenti car je suis là

Comment: @LaurentS. Il n'est pas logique non plus leur demander d'adopter un langage particulier ; le principe du « un pour tous et tous pour un » a des limites, en particulier quand le sacrifice devient trop grand.